# Using a label as a button - when label is touched, assign value to a string

Tags: xcode, button, uibutton, uilabel

I am having some challenges with using a label as a button.  I have a label defined as a UILabel, and declared the string variable in my .h file:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *l1;

@property(strong)NSString *myvariable;
```

In the xib, with the label selected, in the Identity Inspector view, under Document, the Label field with the desired label name is set - example: l1.  I also have some static text in the label.

In File's Owner Connection Inspector, I have the l1 Outlet connected to the l1 label.

My goal:  When the label is touched, I would like to simply assign a string variable with a text value such as what might be done in the .m file:

```
self.myvariable = l1.text;
```

Things that I have unsuccessfully tried: 
 - setting up a UIButton in my .h, 
 - tried to set up a UIButton in the .m
 - in the XIB Identity Inspector view, under Accessibility, tried checking the button Traits checkbox to enable the label as a button

I haven't figured it out yet. This is probably an easy label question, and most of my experience with labels include static text display, or displaying a countdown based on present date using epoch time.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking around, most people recommend using an actual button and setting the background transparent or to the background color.

That said, you can do something like:

In viewWillLoad:

```
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init]; // change/delete to use your obj

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pushAction)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

then set the selector:

```
- (void) pushAction
{
    self.myvariable = l1.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try this evening and see how I do,  I will reply with my results.  Regarding using an actual button, I have a fair amount of text on the label - Maybe I could use a button, and just set word-wrap.  Right now, I am assigning the label.text to the value of the variable.  I'm not sure if there is a way to get the text on the button and then set that to be the value of the variable, but I supposed to could set it manually as well.  Thanks!  Rob

Comment: THanks Matto, I tried to get the above example to work, but was not successful.  However, I went with using an actual button instead of a label, and that worked well!  The only thing I wish was that I could assign whatever content text the button has (something like - self.myvariable = mybutton.text}, rather than have the text in the button, and then also have the text again when I set the variable to the string. But your suggestion of using an actual button looks like the way to go!  Thanks!
Rob

Comment: @user1362308 Hey Rob, I'm surprised it didn't work for you. I'm not sure if your looking to pursue this or not, but if you are, I'd check that you xib file is being loaded (sounds like it is) and that the label is linked. Also 'l1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;' is KEY to the gesture recognizer working. Anyway, if you are curious to find out how to get it to work the other way, feel free to respond.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I appreciate the response - I am moving forward just using button approach, so that will work well for me at this point!  -Rob

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom class extending `UILabel`, which overrides

`- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

You may assign your new custom UILabel in xib's identity inspector.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try this evening and see how I do,  I will reply with my results - Thanks!  Rob

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get this to work, but I was not able to get this to work.  I appreciate your suggestion though!  In the end, I decided to use an actual button and get rid of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *lblname        = [[ UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 120, 200, 35)];
lblname.text            = @"sunil";
lblname.textColor       = [UIColor blueColor];
lblname.textColor       = [UIColor blueColor];
lblname.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:lblname];

UIButton *btnpress      = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnpress.frame          = CGRectMake(10, 180, 300, 20);
[btnpress setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnpress addTarget:self action:@selector(btnpress1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnpress.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:btnpress];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have my whole screen as a button that when pressed changes the text on a label that appears over the button. This is how I did it on xcode:

In the storyboard I dragged a button over to the interface. At the top right where you edit the button I set the button content to "group" instead of text. DO NOT set alpha to 0 on the button. I then dragged a label on top of the button/group.  When ctrl-dragging over the necessary actions and outlets be sure to do it by exposing the left panel of the storyboard. It is likely you will only be able to access the group by mouse after changing the button content type.

Comment: This is not an answer, remove it or it will be put for moderation.